# Reading exif date from ios photo upload

Tags: php, iphone, ios, upload, exif

this seems like a simple question - I have a standard php image upload in place on a website I'm working with that works fine except for an inability to get the DateTime information from photos uploaded via iOS.
I'm able to fetch orientation data and rotate images,etc but I can't for the life of me locate any date taken information.
The information is retrievable from an iOS photo uploaded via PC (i.e. after it has been imported from the iPhone/iPad) just not from the iDevice itself.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the date taken from an iOS photo through php upload? If so where should I be looking in the EXIF?

Answer (score 1):

Photos uploaded, via safari mobile, are stripped of most of the metadata including datetime and geolocation. The only metadata you receive is:

- ColorSpace
- Exif IFD Pointer
- Orientation
- PixelXDimension
- PixelYDimension

If you transfer the photo to your desktop browser and upload then the metadata will exist. Also if you use a Hybrid-Native or Native app you can retain photo metadata.

This data was obtained through testing an EXIF data parser in javascript. I couldn't find actual Apple documentation mentioned this "feature"

Answer (score 0):

Using the https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exif-read-data.php and the FILE FileDateTime =

> $arrImageData = read_exif_data($web_dir);
> $datetime = $arrImageData["FILE"]["FileDateTime"];

As its seems to be, I don't know which EXIF gives the iOS

Comment: ["file"]["FileDateTime"] returns a timestamp that gives the date the file is uploaded as far as I can teel from trying out (uploading n image with a known date)

Comment: Wow so that's another problem of the iOS, try with filectime() but I think that is only effective in Windows... I've never been in this. Maybe you'll have to read headers, decode them or another thing to achieve this hard mission

Comment: The function works but returns the timestamp the file arrives on the server, which isn't a great deal of help :(